# codeigniter rewrite URL to lowercase

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-2

How to make the URL to be always in lowercase even if user types in an uppercase URL??
This is done in facebook even if we type uppercase URL it converts it to lowercase.

I have tried some of the things in htaccess but they are not working for me...

NO ONE CAN HELP......???

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function?

Comment: you can use $this->uri->segment(n) in combo with this function.  But I don't know if thats actually a solution but a bandaid.

Comment: in my site i have a search box and whatever user types and if it exists in DB then it goes to domainname.com/text now if user changes this text to an uppercase then I am facing problem I want it to be always lowercase no matter what.

Comment: Maybe you need two rounds of redirection, or adding an useless query string snippet... because merely changing the case may not trigger an action from the browser... Anyway, it should be easy to do a "strtolower" equivalent with URL rewrite rules in the HTTP server, before reaching CI/PHP code.

Comment: There is this code but its not working:      RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]

Comment: I have used var search = $("#search_txt").val().toLowerCase();
    location.href= "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+search; when user searches text from box but what if he changes the URL in the browser at that time I want it to be lowercase

Answer (score 0):

I found out this on CI forumn....here is the code rest all is useless.......!!!

```
$server_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($server_url !== strtolower($server_url))
{
  header('Location: http://' . strtolower($server_url), TRUE, 301);
}
```